# Find the area of all triangles from an output of Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am detecting roadline pattern in an image. I have applied delaunay triangulation. 
I get 160 triangles in that. Now I need to find the area for each triangle. Can you kindly help me. Only after this I should proceed with my project. Please help me...
 [image: delaunay triangulation]

Comment: what kind of info do you have? The coordinates of the vertex, or the edges?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use following matrix form, while given vertices pairs $(x_i, y_i) $:

$A = \dfrac{1}{6} \det \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & y_2 & 1\\x_3 & y_3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  = \dfrac{1}{2}( x_3y_1 + x_1y_2+x_2y_3-x_3y_2-x_1y_3-x_2y_1)$

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of not really a DSP question, but assuming that the triangles are defined sufficiently (eg. you can calculate edge lengths, angles etc.), each triangle has an area of its base multiplied by its height, divided by $2$.